# Getting mouse coordinates Qt OpenGL

Tags: c++, qt, mouse, mouseevent, mousemove

I have an openGL widget and know that I can get the coordinates of my mouse as follows:

```
X = this->mapFromGlobal(QCursor::pos()).x();
Y = this->mapFromGlobal(QCursor::pos()).y();
```

Lets imagine my mouse is at (X, Y) position on widget. Now I want to press the mouse left button on widget and move the cursor to another place again in widget (lets say (X', Y')), and then unpress the left button of mouse.

Q: How to keep (X,Y) and (X', Y')?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The simplest solution is to store them as members, like this:

```
class MyGLWidget: public QGLWidget
{
    // ...

private:
    int xAtPress, yAtPress;
};

void MyGLWidget::mousePressEvent(QMouseEvent * event)
{
    xAtPress = event->x();
    yAtPress = event->y();
}

void MyGLWidget::mouseReleaseEvent(QMouseEvent * event)
{
    int xAtRelease = event->x();
    int yAtRelease = event->y();

    // example code
    int dx = xAtRelease - xAtPress;
    int dy = yAtRelease - yAtPress;
    translateObject(dx,dy);
}
```

Note: using `event->pos()` already gives you the mouse position in widget coordinate, it is much better than using `mapFromGlobal(QCursor::pos())`

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Could you please explain why you do translation at the end?

Comment: @Mike Glad it was helpful :-) The translation was just a dummy example to show a possible use where you need both {x|y}atPress and {x|y}atRelease. I've chosen this example because it's a common use case, just ignore it if it's confusing ;-)

Comment: @Mike: I have seen your suggested edit that has been rightfully rejected (the policy is not to edit things that changes the meaning, since the author of the post may disagree). In this case, I indeed disagree: `event->pos()` always gives you the position of the cursor relative to the top-left corner of the widget (doc: `Returns the position of the mouse cursor, relative to the widget that received the event`). I've never seen this failed after years of usage, including extensive usage with `QGLWidget`. I would be interested in seeing a counter-example if you know one.